# JQuery How to get selector with x2 .next() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

This situation have been post a lot in there but I didn't find the best way to solve my problem. Please help me this.

```
enter code here
```

> [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dhhuy0704/hsvrzo4u/2/)

I want to make the button to open/hide the table content. I used slideToggle() in JQuery and next() to cacth the table content.In jsfiddle you can see. My code is worked.

But it just on the **Click to SHOW/HIDE (worked)** the **Click to SHOW/HIDE (not work)** is the MAIN button which I want to make (BECAUSE THE DESIGN). But when I put the button in there, it didn't work anymore. How can I solve this. Please help !

Comment: Assign a id attribute to the div containing the table and use that div to catch hold of the div to toggle the content. Someone will help you with code if you post a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: @TommyDo, your fiddle demo is not working..

Comment: Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/hsvrzo4u/4/

Comment: @syd: thank for your help. But this is too simple. My customer requirement is making many tables with this function and save the state when they open/hide the table and refresh the browser. I can't apply your suggestion for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

check this demo, if you are expecting the same thing

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/hsvrzo4u/4/)

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggleMe" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```